# Webmin - View log of visitors to a particular webpage

Tags: linux, webmin

Is there a way with Webmin to see a log of all IPs who have tried to access a particular webpage on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a log file analyzer. As it is, this is not something Webmin does.

You can use AWStats which may be installed with Webmin depending upon how your server was built. But AWStats is rather limited and poor compared to Piwik.

Piwik is FREE and likely the very best out there. You can download it from their website: http://piwik.org/ If I remember right, Webmin has a module for Piwik. This is the route I recommend.